# How to check if a 2D array is out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays

The method `isFilledAt()` returns `true` if the shape has a filled block at the given `row/col` position and `false` if the block is empty. If the position is out of bounds, raise a `FitItException` with an informative message. Im running a nested loop to get the position and having trouble how to figure out if a position is out of bounds. Could smb help out? Thanks in advance!

```
public class CreateShape {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char dc;
    private Rotation initialPos;


    public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.dc = dc;
        initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
    }
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col) 
    {
        char[][] tempArray = new char[height][width];
        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < tempArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(row > tempArray.length || row < 0)
                    throw new FitItException("Out of Bounds!");

                if(tempArray[row][col] == dc)
                    return true;
            }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the method `isFilledAt` supposed to do? Surely `tempArray` should be an instance variable, and the method should test one of its entries? At the moment `tempArray` is a local variable, so the changes you make to it are lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the `row` or `col` are less than zero, or if `row` is greater than or equal to the `height`, or if `col` is greater than or equal to the `width`. Note you only need to do the validation once, so you could move the check outside the loop:

```
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col)  {
    if (row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width) {
        throw new FitItException("Out of Bounds!");
    }
    char[][] tempArray = new char[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (tempArray[row][col] == dc) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note however that `isFilledAt()` may not work as you intend. Since you recreate `tempArray` every time you call the method, the condition `tempArray[row][col] == dc` will probably never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Nikolay Glad to help! Though this should solve the "out of bounds" problem. There still seems to be something off in your code regarding `tempArray`. You should consider pbabcdefp comment about it.

Comment: What do you mean something is off in the tempArray? Is there smth wrong with the loops? @AndersonVieira

Comment: @Nikolay I added a small explanation at the end of the answer.

Comment: You seem to be right though I havent tested yet, @AndersonVieira. However, as I understood the intialization of the char[][] array should be out of the method, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Nikolay You probably want to have a `char[][]` instance field in `CreateShape` and fill it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your isFilledAt method as follows

```
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col) 
{
    char[][] tempArray = new char[height][width];
    // Calls the method that fills tempArray datas

    if ( (row >= height || row <0)  || (col >= width || col < 0)) {
         throw new FitItException("Out of Bounds!");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
                if(tempArray[row][col] == dc)
                return true;
        }


   }
   return false;
}
```

You place your return false at the wrong place: it would systematically return false if the looked up value was not inside the first row. Instead do a return false after every row has been iterated